# How do you grep and save 2 different results into one file without them overwriting each other?

Tags: terminal, grep

I am using terminal to grep the results of two different files and save them into one file. However each time I grep the second file it overwrites the first file. Is there a way to avoid this? Ideally, I would like each result on a separate line.

I am using these commands:

```
grep 'SEE INTERVIEW #47246024' streets/Hart_Place > interviews.txt
grep 'SEE INTERVIEW #699607' streets/Buckingham_Place > interviews.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is to run the two commands in a subshell and collect the output of the subshell:

```
(grep 'SEE INTERVIEW #47246024' streets/Hart_Place; \
 grep 'SEE INTERVIEW #699607' streets/Buckingham_Place ) > interviews.txt
```

Comment: This answer not only answers my question but allows me to use grep more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to replace second `>` by `>>` to append data.